# two way data binding between nested template content and a parent element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way in polymer to make two-way data-binding between nested template content and a parent element?

Element1:

```
<dom-module id='my-element1'>
  <template>
     [[data]]
     <div id="content">
        <content selector="element-content"></content>
     </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element1',
    properties: {
      data: String,
      _dataElement2: String
    }
  });
</script>
```

Element2:

```
<dom-module id='my-element2'>
  <template>
     [[data]]
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element2',
    properties: {
      data: String
    }
  });
</script>
```

Nesting:

```
<my-element1 data='{{data}}'>
  <element-content>
    <my-element2></my-element2>
  </element-content>
</my-element1>
```

I have found an ugly way to set data attribute for nested element2 inside element1:

```
this.$.content.children[0].children[0].setAttribute('data', this.data);
```

[here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrQ9cD?p=preview)

But my goal is to make two way data-binding between `_dataElement2` of the parent element1 and `data` of the element2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set data to a nested element:

```
Polymer.dom(this).firstElementChild.firstElementChild.set('data', this.dataToSet);
```

receive data from a nested element:

```
ready() {
    Polymer.dom(this).firstElementChild.firstElementChild.addEventListener('data-changed', this._onChildDataChange.bind(this));
},

_onChildDataChange(e) {
    console.log('received data is', e.detail.value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set a data-binding to the `data` on `my-element2`like this:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <my-element1 data='{{data}}'>
    <element-content>
      <my-element2 data="{{data}}"></my-element2>
    </element-content>
  </my-element1>
</template>
```

This will bind the `data` properties in both `my-element1` and `my-element2` to a `data` property in the `dom-bind`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtLLxbqL/1/) with a working example.

Bear in mind you need to set the `data` properties in both `my-element1` and `my-element2` as `notify: true` for this to work. ([Here's why](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification))

Comment: well it is completely not what i want. As I wrote I need 2way data binding between `_dataElement2` of the parent element1 and `data` of the element2. And yes `_dataElement2` should be private. The reason I do this is because I need to pass modified data to nested element via `_dataElement2`. And this modification should be done inside parent. In the other hand nested element should be able to change `_dataElement2` of the parent element.