# How to add an event listener to a custom element property in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a child custom element with `data` property.
My goal is to assign an event listener to this property (using javascript and not {{}} data-bind syntax) in the context of the parent element.

I search something like this:

```
ready(){
    this.addEventListener(this.$.childElememt.data, _onChildDataChange);
},

_onChildDataChange() {   
   //called when data property of child elememt changes     
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of adding that event listener? A property doesn't fire events, only elements do. Do you want to get notified when the value of `data` changes? What kind of property is `data`?  A primitive value like num or String or a complex object?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, data is an json object. Yes I want to receive notification. Purpose is to implement 2way data binding between nested template content and parent element. see my initial issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098945/two-way-data-binding-between-nested-template-content-and-a-parent-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Polymer, properties that have `notify: true` set on them will cause the element to fire a non-bubbling `<property>-changed` event that their parent can listen to.

I suspect you could listen to this event manually (provided that the child property is set up to notify) by doing something like this:

```
ready() {
    this.$.childElement.addEventListener('data-changed', this._onChildDataChange.bind(this));
},

_onChildDataChange() {   
   //called when data property of child element changes     
}
```

However, this is effectively equivalent to just using the two-way data-binding syntax on the child with an observer on the parent property, so I would recommend that you do that instead if possible. The data-binding is basically already doing the exact same thing for you.

Comment: My work projects are heavily invested in Polymer, so I spent a lot of time dissecting Polymer to figure out how its internals and features work, but some of these implementation details are eluded to here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification

Comment: ok, thx. I see that `this._onChildDataChange` function has a scope of the child element BUT is defined in the parent element.. Do you know how to access scope of parent from this function?

Comment: Sure, just switch it from this._onChildDataChange to this._onChildDataChange.bind(this)